# Two flex containers with the same width independently of items

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How to create two containers with equal width even if there are a lot of flex items inside one of them? I could add overflow hidden to both containers but it seems to be workaround rather than solution of the problem

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1">
    blabla
  </div>
  <div class="child2">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="subcontainer">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
      <div class="subcontainer">bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</div>
      <div class="subcontainer">ccccccccccccccccccccccc</div>
      <div class="subcontainer">dwadawdwdaadwawadawddwaw</div>
      <div class="subcontainer">dddddddddddddddddddddddd</div>
      <div class="subcontainer">eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.parent {
  display: flex;
}

.child1, .child2 {
  flex: 1;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  /* overflow: hidden */
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.child1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.child2 {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0e7n6g8b/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add flex-wrap:wrap; to your container div.

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
```

Thanks